# how many times a unique "callingNumber" is recorded for the same "CallReasonName"

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

i need to get your help regarding the below cases. i have a table with two columns "CallingNumber" that contain different redundant phone numbers and "CallReason" the reason for why they recorded.

```
 then i need a query to generate 
     => how many times a unique "callingNumber" is recorded for the same "CallReasonName".
```

Comment: without seeing the table structure and some sample data it is impossible to suggest anything..

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty The table structure is mentioned in the question, and sample data might make it clearer, but it's not required.

Comment: To the OP: you've tagged this both MySQL and SQL Server. Which is it? And have you started on a query? At what point to you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand you well or not, but I think it is a simple Query as

```
Select callingNumber, CallReasonName, count(1) as Cnt
from table
Group by callingNumber, CallReasonName
```

Comment: @user3100545 I'm glad it helped, please mark your question as answered to remove it from unanswered questions list

Comment: sorry can you tell me how can i do this ?

Comment: @user3100545 There is a white check mark beside my answer (under up/down vote) just click on it.